# помогите разобраться с openSSL api

Tags: c, openssl

Впервые пытаюсь выполнить https запрос. Использую данный [мануал](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-openssl/), вроде все получается. Вот только не совсем понял, что делать если адрес например такого типа: "хттпс://uuu.ru:4001/Gateway/Client"(прим.).
Не совсем понял как правильно в таком случае открыть защищенное соединение. 
В примере приведено след.:

```
BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, "hostname:port");
if(BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0)
{
    /* Handle failed connection */
}
```

в статье есть ещё такой пример:

```
BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, "www.verisign.com:https");
```

как задать необходимый мне хвост "4001/Gateway/Client"? 
[manual](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-openssl/)

Comment: А теперь нужно либо найти в OpenSSL функции, которые будут слать GET/POST запросы, либо самому формировать соответствующий буфер и слать его как по вашей ссылке написано. Можно еще использовать готовые библиотеки типа curl, что еще лучше, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Отделяйте "мух" от "котлет". OpenSSL не реализует протокол HTTP. SSL/TLS является лишь "слоем" шифрования данных/гарантии их целостности, не более того. Протокол прикладного уровня необходимо реализовать самостоятельно, либо воспользоваться готовыми решениями типа libcurl, которая, как правило, собирается с libssl.

Comment: как же это было давно, в любом случае спасибо